# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;

Tags: android, android-library, jacoco

I have an android application which depends on some android libraries I have built on my own. 
If I build the application with the library dependencies specified in the build.gradle then I get the following exception.

```
-6694/com.mycompany.myproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-10 18:47:55.986 6694-6694/com.mycompany.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.mycompany.myproject, PID: 6694
                                                                        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;
                                                                            at com.mycompany.ui.components.ListArrayAdapter.$jacocoInit(ListArrayAdapter.java)
                                                                            at com.mycompany.ui.components.ListArrayAdapter.<init>(ListArrayAdapter.java)
                                                                            at com.mycompany.myproject.NationalityFragment.onCreateView(NationalityFragment.java:47)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

If I remove the dependencies and instead copy the concerned classes from the libraries and run the application, it runs perfectly fine. 
Also I have other dependencies like junit and app-compat and those don't seem to cause this issue. Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

- I have tried specifying the jacoco plugin to the following version
  and it still doesn't seem to work.
- I have tried removing jacoco dependencies from the libraries : no
  effect.

My main build.gradle looks like this :

```
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.ext.set('compileSdkVersion', 23)
    project.ext.set('buildToolsVersion', '23.0.3')

    project.ext.set('minSdkVersion', 19)
    project.ext.set('targetSdkVersion', 23)
    project.ext.set('versionCode', 1)
    project.ext.set('versionName', '1.0-SNAPSHOT')

    project.ext.set('javaVersion', JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7)

    group 'com.mycompany.myproject'
    version = project.ext.get('versionName')

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I got this error after updating Android Studio. I found out that switching off Instant Run in Settings fixed it.

Comment: Where in Settings is the Instant Run option?  I'm not seeing it in Android Studio 1.5.1, so it may not exist in older versions.

Comment: @Tbadams Instant Run is currently available only in Android Studio 2.0, and higher. So if you have this problem in older version, the reason may be different

Answer (score 3):

According to [here](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html), you'll need to `jacocoagent.jar` put on the classpath. In other words, you'll need to compile the same version of `jacocoagent.jar` in gradle.

First check the version code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/core/jacoco.properties?av=f)(In your situation is version`0.7.4.201502262128`) and then download jars from [here](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/).

Put `jacocoagent.jar` in libs folder then add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['jacocoagent.jar'])` in your app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on both the library and the application. Nothing seems to have changed. I am wondering if my implementation has a flaw that is causing this exception to pop up only in my case. I don't see many others facing this issue! :-/

Comment: Same issue 5 years later.

Answer (score 1):

bijang is correct. You need to add the jacocoagent.jar. Rather than including the jar directly, pull it down from maven. The version of the jacocoagent has to match the version of the jacocoplugin since the Offline.class package has a commmit hash.  Here are my dependencies:

compile 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9'

compile 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.9:runtime'

Comment: Did not work. Not even ```classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7:runtime'```

Answer (score 1):

For Jacoco 0.8.7 i added the following to the `app/build.gradle` to resolve the issue

```
implementation 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7'
```